# How to install glibc-2.23

Tags: linux, glibc

I'm installing glibc-2.23 on linux.

Running `../configure --prefix=$HOME/local` outputs:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/yejiacheng/glibc-2.23/build':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details
```

Here is the config.log:

This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU C Library configure (see version.h), which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

```
  $ ../configure --prefix=/home/yejiacheng/local 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = SH-IDC1-10-140-0-183
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Wed Feb 23 16:47:03 UTC 2022


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2188: checking build system type
configure:2202: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2222: checking host system type
configure:2235: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2304: checking for gcc
configure:2320: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2331: result: gcc
configure:2560: checking for C compiler version

configure:2580: $? = 0
configure:2569: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-8.5.0 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-8.5
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.5.0 (GCC) 
configure:2580: $? = 0
configure:2569: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2580: $? = 1
configure:2569: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2580: $? = 1
configure:2585: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2607: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
configure:2611: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/"
| #define PKGVERSION "(GNU libc) "
| #define REPORT_BUGS_TO "<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2625: error: in `/home/yejiacheng/glibc-2.23/build':
configure:2627: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details
...
```

Anys helps on this?

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
configure:2607: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
configure:2611: $? = 1
```

means that the `gcc` on your `$PATH` (use `which gcc` to find out which `gcc` that is) is not working / is installed incorrectly.

Without a working `gcc` you can't compile *anything* and GLIBC is no exception.